# Why are rings assumed to be unital in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we consider a non-unital ring , for example, the ring of  even numbers, the spectrum of it contains a closed point $(2)$ and a generic point $(0)$, everything seems ok. So what is the idea behind the convention?

Comment: The category of (possibly) nonunital rings is equivalent to the category of unital rings with an augmentation map $R \to \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the category of "non-unital affine schemes" is equivalent to the category of usual affine schemes equipped with a  choice of basepoint $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \text{Spec}(R)$. In this way, the nonunital rings don't actually buy us anything new. See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34332/consequences-of-not-requiring-ring-homomorphisms-to-be-unital) for more.

Comment: See Bjorn Poonen's *Why all rings should have a $1$* where he argues (persuasively, IMO) that this is part of what ought to be meant by associativity: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0135

Comment: @HallaSurvivor You seem to specifically mean [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34377/111897), right? The rest is about the question "Why are *homomorphisms* required to be unital"?